# I got stuck on a system of three equations

Tags: functions

I have this homework problem about functions. The goal is to find a function of form
$$ f(x)=a+bc^{x}, c > 0  $$ $$ and $$ $$ f(0) = 15, f(2)=30, f(4)=90 $$ and then to find the domain of a another function called g(x) where
$$ g(x) = ln(x), x = f(x) $$.

For the first part of the problem, to find a function of form, I created a system of thee equations
$$ \begin{cases} a+bc^0=15\\ a+bc^2=30\\ a+bc^4=90 \end{cases} $$
And this is where I got stuck. I don't know how to solve this system. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subtract the first equation from the second
$$ \tag{1}b(c^2 - 1) = 15$$
Subtract the second equation from the third
$$ \tag{2} b(c^4 - c^2) = bc^2(c^2 - 1) = 60$$
Divide $(2)$ by $(1)$
$$ c^2 = 4$$
It's pretty straightforward from here on.